# Network does not work anymore

Tags: networking, ethernet, led

My Raspberry ran for about a year and was a webserver and samba server.
Suddenly I couldn't connect to the raspberry pi and ping also didnt work anymore. I flashed a new OS to the sd card but I still couldn't connect to my Raspberry Pi over SSH.

I removed the LAN-cable and flashed the SD-card again and booted it up. Look at the LEDs:

[image: Raspberry Pi LEDs light up without LAN cable]

As you can see, i have no cable plugged in. And ifconfig says that there is no eth0.

**Did my network module die?**

Answer (score 1):

Insert a physical loopback into your RJ-45 Ethernet port. Install `hwinfo` and then issue `hwinfo --netcard`, if `link detected` is set to `no` it might be an hardware failure. You may also check `/sys/log/dmesg` and `/sys/log/syslog` for some specific problem with `eth0`.